# Binding to a socket in Tomcat

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat

I am writing a Tomcat app.  As part of its functionality, it needs to send out a UDP multicast when certain events happen.  Right now my code goes something like this (host and group are fake, exception handling ripped out to save space):

```
import java.net.*;
/* ..... */
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(12345);
InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("111.222.333.444");
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, group, 12346);
socket.send(packet);
```

This works fine when I install it into tomcat; however, when I try to install a new version of the app (using "ant remove; ant install;"), I fail to bind to a socket, and get a `java.net.BindException: Address already in use`.  The only way out is to restart Tomcat every time, which is obviously unacceptable.  How do I use sockets in a Tomcat-friendly way?

A couple of clarifications per Pete's answer:

I don't close the socket; it lives in a Singleton.  Adding a method that can close the socket to the Singleton and calling it in the servlet's destroy worked, thank you! It's a bit hacky, I think (exposing a method like that to the world via a public method), but it gets the job done.

Comment: If you just added it to destroy() it shouldn't be hacky, as only the servlet container can call that (not the public as in the users of the webapp) if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you closing the socket after you use it via disconnect() / close()?  What is the lifecycle on the socket - per request, or a singleton?  If it is per request, closing the socket should release it.  If a singleton, you'll need to somehow close it on 'ant remove' - if shutting down / restarting Tomcat is not acceptable, then perhaps your ant script can call some secure page, etc. that closes the socket.  If you can incur a shutdown restart, then close the socket in the servlet's destroy() method.